# How to build a custom material theme based on 8 colors

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-theming

I have this color palete provided by designer

[image]

As you can see it contains 8 colors.

I look up in to the [angular material theming guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-theme) but you may only provide primary, accent colors.

```
$my-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
 color: (
   primary: $my-primary,
   accent: $my-accent,
   warn: $my-warn,
 )
));
```

However in my case I have more colors specified:

```
$primary-color-dark:   #00796B
$primary-color:        #009688
$primary-color-light:  #B2DFDB
$primary-color-text:   #FFFFFF
$accent-color:         #FF5722
$primary-text-color:   #212121
$secondary-text-color: #757575
$divider-color:        #BDBDBD
```

It seems I can skip most of it.

```
$my-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
 color: (
   primary: $primary-color,
   accent: $accent-color,
   warn: $warn-color, //had to confirm this one
 )
));
```

However how would you handle `$primary-text-color` and `$secondary-text-color` ?

Any ideas?